# If I locally precompile, should my images when inspected show the long precompiled name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku

I have a rails 4.0.1 ruby 2.0.0 app.

I'm locally precompiling: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile.

My configurations in production.rb file are:
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true

The images in my app/assets/images folder are in the public/assets folder, for example 'starsw600-xxxlongnumberxxx.png'

When I deploy in Heroku I get " Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally" and my images show up.

My question is when I inspect the image I get 
'background-image
url("http://abc-abc-abc.herokuapp.com/assets/starsw600.png")'

Same as when I don't precompile. When I inspect the element shouldn't I get
'background-image
url("http://abc-abc-abc.herokuapp.com/public/assets/starsw600-xxxlongnumberxxx.png")'

thus verifying that heroku is using the locally precompiled images that I made?

When I change config.assets.compile to false 'config.assets.compile = false' the images don't show.

So question is: If I locally precompile, should my images when inspected show the long precompiled name?

This is my stylesheet ricardoorangetest/app/assets/stylesheets/show.css.scss

```
.stars {
  background-image:image_path('/starsw600.png');
  height:30px;
  width:600px;
  //background-color:#ffffff;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border-color:#190c00;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:2px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you set serve_static_assets to false?

Comment: @davidfurber config.assets.compile = true and config.serve_static_assets = false yields the same. Same being "detected manifet file...compiled locally" and inspecting image gives .../assets/starsw600.png.

Comment: @davidfurber config.assets.compile=false and config.serve_static_assets=false yields no images.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using Heroku, and consequently have to serve static assets, you'll have to work with [asset fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) regardless of how you precompile

---

**Dynamic Paths & Precompiling**

We had this problem with Heroku, and we found the best way to fix the issue is to use dynamic asset paths, with [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Instead of using the static CSS methods of calling images:

```
#assets/application.css    
background-image: url('/img/file.png');
```

The problem here is CSS cannot dynamically render the image paths, meaning that when you run the production app, you'll never see the images. The fix for this is to use SCSS like this:

```
#assets/application.css.scss
background-image: image_path('/img/file.png');
```

This will compile the image correctly, allowing it to show in Heroku

---

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still have the same results. Substituting image_path('/img/starsw600.png') did not make a difference. I tried /images/starsw600.png and just 'starsw600.png'.  What I really would like to know is when you open up the web page and you inspect the element do you see "filename.png" or do you see "filename-xxxnumbsxxx.png". I mean I can get the images to show, I just don't know if they are showing from the precompiled file or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Did you put the `image_path` method in SCSS, or just plain CSS? If you used just plain CSS, the likelihood is that it wouldn't work. Also, are you calling assets or uploaded images?

Comment: my style sheet is show.css.scss. How do you know my images are not showing correctly? Is it because they don't show up as the long compile name? Is it because they should be showing even with config.assets.compile = false? I still have my original question. How do I know that the locally compiled files are being used? I think if you could get me to that point, where I know there's a problem and I can identify when the problem is solved, I could continue on my own.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'calling assets or uploaded images'. I have some images in app/assets/images/ folder. I locally compile them with 'RAILS_ENV = production bundle exec rake assets:precompile'. They show up in the public/assets folder.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! The difference between asset-based images is they are "static" (used in CSS), and are in the assets/images folder. On the other hand, if you use Paperclip or similar, those images are independent of the assets folder completely :)

Comment: Okay, so your stylesheet is showing just the small names? Can you copy & paste the contents of your "live" show.css.scss into an edit of your original Q?

When you precompile in the "production" environment for Rails, the precompiler will create the long (fingerprinted) filenames, which will need to be dynamically linked (hence my answer). Having those names means all your asset files have been minimized & compiled correctly, and consequently if you're not seeing that, and using `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, it means something else is causing problems, which we need to fix

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41423/discussion-between-flobacca-and-rich-peck)